# How to Declare Styled Components Using React Component Class Syntax

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

How does one declare styled components outside of a React component's `render()` method when using React class syntax?

My motivation is stateful components being accidentally remounted. They are remounted due to their parents being styled components and declared in the `render()` method. This causes the parents to be recreated every render, and thus their children's state reseting. This topic is discussed on the [styled-components FAQ](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/faqs#why-should-i-avoid-to-declare-styled-components-in-the-render-method).

Comment: How is that different to the example provided in the docs you linked? Just declare them outside of your class component and render them as usual.

Comment: You can declare them outside of the component and they'll be global.   Or in-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we do is create styled component outside render and then user it:

```
example.jsx // statefull component

const StyledDiv = styled.div `
   .... styles
`;

class Header extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
    ... use StyledDiv here
   );
  };
 } ;
```

Comment: I had not thought of declaring the component *completely* outside of the parent component's class. I thought all child components needed to be defined inside the parent component for React to correctly determine how to update the DOM.

Comment: one more pattern I have seen where you can put all these styles components in single file src/components/Styled/example.jsx. Now export and use it in different components. This is good when application grows and re usability is required.